# Congruence class solutions of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

I'm not sure how to find the congruence class solutions of linear equations or systems of linear equations.

For example, how would you solve $3x + 4y \equiv  4\pmod 6$?

Comment: Well, you only need to test $x,y=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: $x$ even, $y\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Hi Andre! How did you solve that? Sorry-- I'm quite new to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

$3x+4y=6k+4\implies 2|3x\implies 2|x,x=2x_0$

$6x_0+4y=6k+4\implies 6|(4y-4)\implies y\equiv1,4\pmod{6}$